# change pydantic 'extra=' behaviour per call

Tags: python, pydantic

i want to define a pydantic BaseModel with extra='forbid', and then in specific places validate objects i know will have extras, while still disallowing them if not specified - is this possible?

if not what's most concise or generally recommended approach? intermediate class? classmethod on the model? typeadaptor? utility converter function?

im interested in general, although my specific case was handling pydantic and sqlmodel objects in and out of database, with and without related models

i hoped for something like:

```py
class NoExtras(BaseModel)
    model_config = Dict(
        extra='forbid',
    )
    name:str

somedict = dict(name='aname', extra_field='astring')

validated = NoExtras.model_validate(somedict, allow_extra=True)
```

Comment: I would think a separate model that *doesn't* use `forbid` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As of pydantic version 2.6.4, you cannot modify the behavior of `extra` on a per-call basis. However, you can easily remove the extra fields from the input to achieve equivalent behavior:

```py
validated = NoExtras.model_validate({key:value for key,value in somedict.items() if key in NoExtras.model_fields})
```

Be aware, this only works for flat models.

Comment: Did you mean to say `if in... ` rather than `not in`? Otherwise I'm confused! In any case this is a decent workaround.

Comment: Mistake, of course. Corrected.